# Apply value of var to another var in loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_button').click(function(){
        if ($('#id_text').val()==='')
            alert('Enter Your Id to proceed');
        else {
            $('body').load('attendee.html');
            alert(UID_USER);
        }
    });
});
```

Here the var `UID_USER` is a variable of `attendee.html`. How do I set the value of it from this page with the value of id_text?

Comment: Set it from *what*? End-user input? The contents of the `id_text` field?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set the value of it from this page with the value of id_text?

You *pass* the value to `attendee.html` in some way, perhaps on the query string:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_button').click(function(){
        var id = $('#id_text').val();
        if (id ==='')
            alert('Enter Your Id to proceed');
        else {
            $('body').load('attendee.html?' + encodeURIComponent(id));
        }
    });
});
```

Code on the `attendee.html` page would look on `location.search` at page load for the query string information. and assign it to `UID_TEXT`:

```
// Get the id from the query string, skipping the ? character
UID_TEXT = location.search ? decodeURIComponent(location.search.substring(1)) : "";
```

Comment: UID_USER is a variable of attendee.html

Comment: @AritraBasu: Right, that's why I said *"Code **on the `attendee.html` page**..."* for the second bit.

Comment: @AritraBasu: I forgot to decode the ID when receiving it, updated above.

Comment: This method is not working...I am getting null value on the other page

Comment: @AritraBasu: You'll have to show more of the code, then; the above *does* work.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){        
  var UID_USER = location.search ? location.search.substring(1) : "";
  alert(UID_USER);
 });

Comment: This is written in script of attendee.html and it returns blank alert. I am not trying to encode right now

Answer (score 0):

I assume that somewhere in attendee.html is present something like:

```
var UID_USER = "Some Value";
```

in that case you're able to access this value only after the page is loaded;

```
$('body').load('attendee.html', function(){
  alert(UID_USER);
});
```

Checkout [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

Comment: how do i use the data sent via load method parameter?

Comment: that way: $('body').load('attendee.html', {data; "value"}, function(){
  alert(UID_USER);
});

Comment: no I mean how do i receive the value in attendee.html?

Comment: But, is attendee.html a static page or is it served by a webserver?